# Phonegap How to Start an Activity for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, skype-for-business

I'm trying to start an activity to start Skype for Business from my android phonegap application but I can't.
I've tried to implement native java codes [Skype Git](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Skype-for-Business-Android-Uri-Sample) for Skype for business api but it's giving error on startActivity part.
I just want to know, how can I start phonegap activity for below code ? If I add                 startActivity(callIntent), it's giving error on build.

```
  String uriString = "ms-sfb://call?id=000000";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to start.

```
this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this,callIntent,0);
```